# can you include sqlite database in a cordova app

Tags: sql, cordova

Yes, I'm still using plain old cordova, the problem is the lack of new tutorials
The question is this
can you include a database (like sqlite) within a cordova app (and I mean include and not connect to a server), if the answer is yes then how?
Thanks

Comment: Unsure what `plain old Cordova` means relative to seeking new tutorials? Anyway, based on other info around here on SO, it seems that SQLite is [now a plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/8.x/cordova/storage/storage.html#sqlite-plugin) to Cordova... maybe start there?

Comment: Alternatively, if you plan on going NoSQL, you can check https://github.com/globules-io/MongOGX